# Services cannot be added more than once

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, gatt

Using the following code to re-publish my Bluetooth service, I intermittently get a crash with the error message below.

```
self.stopAdvertising()
peripheralManager.removeAllServices()
if let service = self.cbService {
  NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.1)
  peripheralManager.addService(service)
  self.startAdvertising()
}
```

2016-06-03 09:32:10.262 BottleSimulator[180:3587] *** Assertion failure in -[CBPeripheralManager addService:], /SourceCache/CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth-256/CBPeripheralManager.m:307
2016-06-03 09:32:10.270 BottleSimulator[180:3587] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Services cannot be added more than once'

Why am I getting this?  I would think that the call to `removeAllServices()` would protect against this.  I even added a sleep for testing, but it didn't stop the intermittent crashes.

Is there a more reliable way to re-publish a service?

Comment: Why don't you start advertising at the end of the for loop?

Comment: Sure, I can try moving startAdvertising() to the end of the block -- but it is not a loop, it is just an if block protecting against a nil service.  So I think it is equivalent either way.

Comment: Why are you republishing the service like that anyway? I suspect you have a timing problem. You have unpublished the service but the Bluetooth process may not have had time to clean up before you add it again. If you do want to re-publish the service it would be better to create a new CBMutableService rather than reusing the existing one.

Comment: The only point in restarting the service in the code shown is to force close any connections from centrals and start from a clean slate.  I am doing this because I am building a peripheral simulator app that can pretend to be one of several peripherals.  Each time I change which peripheral it is acting as, I need to start from a clean slate.  Is there a better way?